# Python: why replace function and for loop is acting weird on my program?

Tags: python

```
matcher = re.compile(r"hklay1\s+(.*?)\s+kppt1", re.DOTALL)
for i in xrange(1, 5):  
    with open("data{}.txt".format(i), "r") as f:  
        with open("nwirp{}.upw".format(i), "r") as f2:
            with open("data{}.upw".format(i), "w") as out:
                    content = matcher.findall(f.read()) 
                    print content
                    for line in f2:
                        lines = line.replace('5.0472640E-03', 'content')
                        out.write("".join(lines))
```

content in the written files should be number, but content becomes content like this

## UPW: Upstream Weighting package file created on 4/12/2016 by ModelMuse version 3.6.2.0.

## created in modelUtils.py

## 2nd line

9 -8.888000000000E+003  0 0 # Data Set 1, IUPWCB HDRY NPUPW IPHDRY
 1 0 # LAYTYP
 1 0 # LAYAVG
 -1 -1 # CHANI
 1 1 # LAYVKA
 0 0 # LAYWET
INTERNAL 1.0 (FREE)    12 # HK Layer 1 Layer 1
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content 
 content  content  content  content  content  content

Could anyone please tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: `.replace()` changes all of the occurring values. So it depends on your data how many times replace is working.

Comment: I got it, but content should be number. Why is it becoming word?

Answer (score 1):

The quotes around `'content'` in the `lines.replace(...)`.

Comment: @BulbulAhmmed No he means that you should remove the quotes and use the variable called content... what you've done is pass a string in not the contents of the variable `content`.